# Why String.split(regexp) for empty string results in String[] having length 1?

Tags: java, string, split

Can someone explain this behaviour:

```
"one,two,three".split(",").length == 3
"one,two".split(",").length == 2
"one".split(",").length == 1
"".split(",").length != 0 // eek!
```

Comment: What exactly? That splitting an empty string will not produce an empty array?

Comment: Why are you surprised by line 4 but not line 3?  Both input strings lack a comma.

Comment: The `split` method splits the string into tokens which are separated by a comma. The third line contains one token. There it returns a one-element array. The fourth line contains no tokens. So why doesn't it return a zero-element array?

Comment: It doesn't contain no tokens, it contains one token, which is the literal string `""`.

Comment: why? Because it does!

Comment: @luk2302 it does *not* produce an empty array. It produces a one-element array.

Comment: check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java) post, it may help

Comment: man I am getting tired of ppl downvoting perfectly fair questions. it's disrespectful. stop it! aaaaand happy again :)

Comment: @JackFlamp since this is described in the Javadoc of the `String.split` method, this is a basic example of "does not show research effort". Not that I downvoted, mind you.

Comment: @JackFlamp The question does not explain *why* the OP is surprised by the behavior, nor does it show evidence of prior research.  It may be a "fair" question, but it's not a "good" one.

Comment: sure, he could have elaborated but it is not obvious why splitting an empty string would result in an empty array even after reading the javadoc.

Comment: @JackFlamp Huh? Splitting an empty string doesn't result in an empty array.  That's sort of the point.

Comment: @azurefrog oh shit I misread the code. I though it read `"".split(",").length == 0`. I get it then

Comment: @JackFlamp ...and that's why I think the question would be improved with some explanatory text ;-)

Comment: @azurefrog I stand corrected :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From javadoc:

> If the expression does not match any part of the input then the
>   resulting array has just one element, namely this string.

`split(regex) -> split(regex, 0)` so take a look on `split(String regex, int limit)`

Answer (score 3):

This behavoiur is consistent:

```
"one".split(",") // {"one"}
"".split(",") // {""}
```

The empty String `""` is a String like `"one"`, so it behaves just like that (or any other String).